# Why programmatically created spinners are transparent

Tags: java, android, transparency, android-spinner

I am creating a spinner programmatically:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myList);
                myArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 

                Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MyActivity.this);
                spinner.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
                spinner.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                buttonLayout.addView(spinner);
```

Can anybody help?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The following is the code of the static elements:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_user"
    android:text="@string/txt_user_lbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_2"
    android:text="@string/txt_disease_lbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_user"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dd_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_2"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_1"
    android:text="@string/txt_medicine_lbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dd_2"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dd_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_1"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dd_1">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_Button"
    android:text="@string/add_Button_lbl"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok_Button"
    android:text="@string/ok_Button_lbl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_Button"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit_Button"
    android:text="@string/exit_Button_lbl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ok_Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why do you `findViewById` and not assign it to anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody help?

Use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor, not `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

Your programmatically added `Spinner` is using a holographic widget theme, like `Theme.Holo`. Your "static spinner" -- however you got it -- is using a legacy theme, like `Theme`. If you want them to look the same, they need to use the same theme. Normally, this happens automatically.

If you got `@style/AppTheme` from Eclipse or Android Studio relatively recently (within the past several months), and did not change anything in the generated *styles.xml* files, then this should give you a theme based on `Theme.Holo` when running on an API Level 11+ device or emulator.

You need to Get rid of `android:background` and `android:spinnerMode` from your two  static elements.

Comment: @GingerHead: Also, why are you using two different themes?

Comment: @GingerHead: Since I have no idea how you got two different themes in the same layout in the first place, I cannot answer that. You are not showing how you set up the "static spinner", or where you are specifying your themes (e.g., manifest).

Comment: @GingerHead: If you got `@style/AppTheme` from Eclipse or Android Studio relatively recently (within the past several months), and did not change anything in the generated `styles.xml` files, the this should give you a theme based on `Theme.Holo` when run on an API Level 11+ device or emulator. That fits with what your screenshot shows for the programmatically-added `Spinner`. The real question is why your "static spinner" is using the wrong theme.

Comment: @GingerHead: Correct. They are using the old Android 1.x/2.x theme.

Comment: @GingerHead: Since I have not seen how you are actually creating the other `Spinner`, I have no idea.

Comment: @GingerHead: Get rid of `android:background` and `android:spinnerMode` from your two `<Spinner>` elements.